# Error `You Must Declare Scalar Variable "@...."`

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have created a function for Execute my data

```
Public Function Excuter(ByVal Query As String)
    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then cn.Close()

    cn.Open()
    Try

        cmd.CommandText = (Query)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

        cn.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())

    End Try

End Function
```

and this is my code for insert

```
Excuter("INSERT INTO Table_PatientDetail (Patient_ID , Patient_Name , Age,Sex , Phone_Number , Address, Check_In_ID, Check_Out_ID , Service , Transfer , Patient_Result ) VALUES (@Patient_ID , @Patient_Name , @Age, @Sex , @Phone_Number , @Address, @Check_In_ID , @Check_Out_ID , @Service , @Transfer , @Patient_Result)")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patient_ID", .PatientIDPatientInformation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patient_Name", .PatientNamePatientInformation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", .AgePatientInformation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", .ComboBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone_Number", .PhoneNumPatientInformation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", .AddressPatientInformation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Check_In_ID", .CIID.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Check_Out_ID", .COID.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service", .Cboservice.SelectedValue)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transfer", .TransferPatientInformation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patient_Result", .ComboBox3.Text)
```

When I test it, it shows this ERROR `Must Declare Scalar Variable"@Patient_Name"`; I don't understand it.

Comment: What do you think this error means ? Are you familiar with sql server or any programming language variables ?

Comment: are you setting the Param values **after** the call to `Executer`???  looks that way in the snippets.

Comment: So you have a global variable to execute the command called cmd. (And just this is enough to let me shiver) but you call the Excuter method passing a string filled with parameters BEFORE setting the parameters collection. No to be surprised if sqlserver yells at you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `Excuter` function takes the query string and executes it before you've actually added the parameters to the `cmd` object. A quick and dirty solution would be to simply populate the `Parameters` collection before calling `Excuter`, like this:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Clear() 'Remove any parameters left over from the previous call
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patient_ID", .PatientIDPatientInformation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patient_Name", .PatientNamePatientInformation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", .AgePatientInformation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", .ComboBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone_Number", .PhoneNumPatientInformation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", .AddressPatientInformation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Check_In_ID", .CIID.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Check_Out_ID", .COID.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service", .Cboservice.SelectedValue)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transfer", .TransferPatientInformation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patient_Result", .ComboBox3.Text)
Excuter("INSERT INTO Table_PatientDetail (Patient_ID , Patient_Name , Age,Sex , Phone_Number , Address, Check_In_ID, Check_Out_ID , Service , Transfer , Patient_Result ) VALUES (@Patient_ID , @Patient_Name , @Age, @Sex , @Phone_Number , @Address, @Check_In_ID , @Check_Out_ID , @Service , @Transfer , @Patient_Result)")
```

However, because this code reuses the connection and command across multiple calls, it seems pretty brittle. For example, you'd have to remember to clear the `Parameters` collection every time you call it or you'd end up with very strange errors. I would recommend refactoring your code so that each database call is more self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Executer` which executes the query, and once the query has executed you add the parameters; however, this is too late. You must call the `cmd.Parameters.AddWith(...)` before `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Add a `ParamArray` parameter to the `Executer` Sub that allows you to pass a variable number of parameters to your query. Since you cannot pass the parameter names at the same time easily, just name the parameters `@0`, `@1`, `@2`, ...

```vb
Public Sub Executer(query As String, ParamArray parameters As Object())
    Using cn = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
            For i As Integer = 0 To parameters.Length - 1
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & i, parameters(i))
            Next
            cn.Open()
            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Interaction.MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Note the `Using` statement closes the connection automatically. It does so even if an exception should occur. Note also that I have declared the connection and command objects locally to the method. That way you don't have to track their state across multiple calls.

Now you can call the executer like this (I shortened the query a bit):

```vb
Const InsertPatientDetailSql As String = _
    "INSERT INTO Table_PatientDetail (ID, Name, Age) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)"
Executer(InsertPatientDetailSql, 42, "John Doe", 35)
```

This is a real simplification in the usage of the `Executer`, compared to your approach.